# Regex: How to match string but except when contains substring

Tags: python, regex

I have the following problem:

I want to extract de username or id of facebook links like this:

```
facebook.com/user.1?eav=AfZbZ7Edw
facebook.com/user2?eav=AfZbZ7Edw
facebook.com/profile.php?id=123456789&eav=AfbDMOIcUI0Q3Vj
```

and the result:

```
user.1
user2
123456789
```

Using regex I have this pattern but unfortunately I don't know how to obtain the id after profile.php

The regex pattern:

```
facebook\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)?
```

I really appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could optionally match `profile.php?` instead of making the capture group optional:

```
facebook\.com/(?:profile\.php\?id=)?([\w.]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EEoGP9/1)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question "How to match string but except when contains substring" You can do a negative lookahead to exclude matches when `profile.php` is present

```
facebook\.com/(?!profile\.php)([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)?
```

Then only the first two URLs you provided will match and the output (group 1) will be the usernames in the first two urls.

```py
text='''\
facebook.com/user.1?eav=AfZbZ7Edw
facebook.com/user2?eav=AfZbZ7Edw
facebook.com/profile.php?id=123456789&eav=AfbDMOIcUI0Q3Vj
'''
pattern = r'facebook\.com/(?!profile\.php)([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)?'
print(re.findall(pattern, text)) # ['user.1', 'user2']
```

But simply excluding cases where a substring is present won't get you the ID in the third case like you want. You need a different approach for this.

As [The fourth bird answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75770880/5747944), you can use an optional non-capturing group to match `profile.php?id=` to handle both cases.

Might look look something like this:

```py
pattern = r'facebook\.com/(?:profile\.php\?id=)?([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)?'
print(re.findall(pattern, text)) # ['user.1', 'user2', '123456789']
```